# How to change AVFormatIDKey of AVAudioFormat?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using AVAudioFormat.. I need to change its AVFormatIDKey but its not working.
here is mycode

```
    _format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 sampleRate:kAudRecordingSampleRate channels:1 interleaved:false ];
```

I had tried following things but not working

```
  NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = _format.settings.mutableCopy;
   [recordSettings1 addEntriesFromDictionary:@{
                                         AVFormatIDKey : @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                                         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : @(AVAudioQualityMedium),
                                         }];
```

I had tried @sbooth to set RecordingSetting but crash on mixer connect

```
_format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithSettings:recordSettings];

AVAudioMixerNode *mainMixer = engine.mainMixerNode;
[engine connect:mixer to:engine.mainMixerNode format:_format]; // crash line
```

Crash log

> [AUInterface.mm:536:SetFormat: ([[busArray
> objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)element] setFormat:format
> error:&nsErr])] returned false, error Error
> Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10868 "(null)"

Comment: You're editing a copy of the settings dictionary, not the one held by the `AVAudioFormat` instance. You could try passing your edited dictionary to `-initWithSettings:` to get a new `AVAudioFormat` object although I think the encoder quality key will be ignored because it doesn't relate to the basic format.

Comment: @sbooth I had updated question

Answer (score 2):

Error -10868 is `kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported`.

AVAudioEngine more or less requires PCM for processing so trying to use a format like AAC is unlikely to work. To get compressed output you can use `AVAudioConverter` (or `AVAudioFile`) and run the graph in manual rendering mode and process the output with `AVAudioConverter`.